# After qutebrowser flatpak installed, qute-pass quit working

Tags: flatpak, qutebrowser

I installed qutebrowser via flatpak to try to keep pain with the Qt web libary to a minumum, and it's working great, except that suddenly, the qute-pass userscript no longer works.  It says it tried the correct domains but could find no entries.  If I run pass on the command line, the entries are found.  Invoking from google, e.g., from :process, I get:

Command: /app/share/qutebrowser/userscripts/qute-pass
Status: Userscript exited with status 2.

No pass candidates for URL 'https://www.google.com/' found! (I tried ['www.google.com', 'google.com'])

Any ideas why this could be happening, or how to debug userscripts run from qutebrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't appreciate the extent of "sandboxing" around flatpak packages, and that appeared to be the problem.  I decided to go with the apt qutebrowser package for now, but here is an explanation of what is needed that I missed when I installed:

[Sandbox and challenges](https://github.com/flathub/org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser/wiki)